# Brushed DC-Motor with Shunt Winding running on AC?

Tags: ac, parallel, shunt, brushed-dc-motor

Why can't a brushed DC motor with a shunt winding (stator and rotor windings are connected in parallel) run on AC? As far as I understand it, the stator current should switch polarity at the same time as the rotor switches and therefore the Lorentz force should be pointing in the right direction resulting in a torque that will keep turning the rotor. The only thing that comes into my mind is the fact that the mechanical commutator keeps switching which rotor coils are energized and therefore the rotor coils aren't necessarily in a steady state (current is building up) while the stator field is in a steady state. Could this create a phase difference in current which will ultimately put stator and rotor "out of sync" and therefore no Lorentz force is established?

Comment: What inductance is the field winding?

Answer (score 1):

A DC motor is designed for use with DC. That means the field magnetic circuit will not have been designed to take account of eddy currents as you reverse the field direction twice per cycle with AC. The resulting loss may either be a slight loss of efficiency, or gross overheating.

If operated in parallel, the inductance of the field may be large enough and mismatched from the armature inductance to result in the magnetic fields being out of phase.

Generally, a 'universal' wound motor is operated with stator and rotor in series, to ensure that the current waveforms are in phase, whether you use DC or AC excitation. It also has laminated field iron.

Comment: I think you buried the lead: Parallel ⇒ Voltage waveforms in phase; Series ⇒ Current waveforms in phase.

Comment: Thanks. So the issue is mainly the magnetic fields being out of phase due to different inductances? How come though? The inductance shifts phase by 90°. Also: Does the mechanical commutation play a role in that? Every time the brushes "switch" how do you even get a large enough di/dt to energize the "new" coil before the commutator switches to the next coil?